# Vanilla JS how to update value in local storage array?

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to vanilla javascript and I followed a tutorial that was cut in half for a shopping cart but i managed to continue a bit but I could not find how to update a value in local storage array by pressing a button, can anyone help ?
the function code:

```
function decrease() {
            let cartItems = localStorage.getItem("productsInCart");
            cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems); 
              
            
}
```

and below is a screenshot of my local storage;
[image: local storage]

I need a command to update the amount of inCart decrease by 1

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Do you want to decrease all `inCart` product properties by 1? Or only from a specific product?

Comment: `cartItems.Prod1.inCart = cartItems.Prod1.inCart - 1` or `cartItems.Prod1.inCart -= 1` or `--cartItems.Prod1.inCart` or `cartItems.Prod1.inCart--` ... how would you have done it in the non-vanilla js you are familiar with?

Comment: @3limin4t0r for a specific product so i can decrease the quantity

Answer (score 0):

For all products:

```
if (cartItems) Object.keys(cartItems).forEach(function(key){ 
    if (cartItems[key].inCart > 0)
      cartItems[key].inCart -= 1;
});
```

For one product:

```
if (cartItems && cartItems[product_id] && cartItems[product_id].inCart > 0)
       cartItems[product_id].inCart -= 1;
```

To store the data back to the localStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem( "productsInCart", JSON.stringify( cartItems ));
```

Comment: hi, thank you for the answer but for one product, what will replace product id ? or do i have to add a loop for array length

Comment: The `product_id` is a variable, which contain a necessary identifier of a product (Prod1, Prod2, ...):  `var product_id = "Prod2"` for example. So, declare: `function decrease( product_id ){ ... }` The call example of this function: `decrease("Prod1");`